# Checking HD SMART status on a fresh install

Tags: hard-drive, smart

On a fresh install of 12.04 what is the best/easiest way to see the SMART status of the hard-drive?

Previous ubuntu versions had a nice preinstalled GUI to do so, but I cannot seem to find it anymore.

Comment: For 14.04 and beyond see http://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run (Alt+F2) `palimpsest` (or start `Disk Utility` from the desktop) and look for the `health check` feature.

[image: palimpsest]

Comment: Note that the program is now called "Disks" and its executable is called `gnome-disks`

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Disk Utility** to view S.M.A.R.T. status of HDD.